# Customize view component intellisense tag helper tooltip / documentation in ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: asp.net-core, intellisense, razor-pages, asp.net-core-tag-helpers, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I've created a razor page view component that I'm invoking within a razor page via tag helper in ASP.NET Core 6 (using Visual Studio 2022).

The component works fine and intellisense does come up with the component(s) when I begin to type `<vc...` in the razor page, but the tooltip / popup information that comes up looks generic

[image]

I'm looking for a way to customize this, similar to a summary / param tags for xml documentation. The component lives within the same solution as the razor pages using it if that matters. But I'm not finding where to configure this properly, probably because I'm using the wrong search criteria. I'd like that gray box to display something custom, such as the parameters it's expecting and instances where you'd want to use this view component.

Thanks!